# what service/URL are hit using application

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to know what service/URL are hit from my android application - is there is any way to find out this? Like on desktop using fiddler we know what URL are being hit. Is there is any Tool or application present using which i came to know which URL are hit using my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler works for [Android too](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid).

You just need to force your android device to use your PC/Mac as its proxy wifi connection.

Comment: on emulator browser i am getting URL name but I want to know which url are hit fro my application how to do this? Thanks

Comment: This is what you should be getting http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Observe-Traffic/Tasks/ConfigureColumns Are you not getting this? If not, please post a screenshot of what you're getting through Fiddler.